# How to write to a file (script) the state of a program (sequence of operations executed) - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, streamreader, streamwriter

In java, let's imagine that I have the following class (just an example):

```
class XPTO {

  int a;
  int b;

  public void a() {...}
  public boolean b() {...}
  public String c(int a) {...}

}
```

And then, I do the following sequence of operations (once again, just an example):

1. a;
2. a;
3. b;
4. c(5);

What I want to do is to save that sequence of operations so that later I can run the program again, and, by reading and executing the script be possible to "start from where I ended".

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more concise? What do you mean by _do the following sequence of operations_? Do you mean that you call those methods? If you want to repeat it, why cant you create another method and call the method?

Comment: Imagine that I'm testing in the console some invocations of those methods. And I call method a, next a again, next b, next c. And then I finish the program (by finish I mean end the program clicking in the red square). Now, when I run the program I want to read and execute the instructions that supposedly are in the script that I generate when I run the first time.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).